# Uploading 4GB file to Amazon-S3

Tags: xml, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm doing some very simple data mining (actually, just a wordcound) as my research project for undergrad program.

I'm going to use Amazon Elastic MapReduce.

I need to upload 4GB .xml file.

What is the best way to do it?

Upload small zip files and somehow unzip them in the bucket?
Or split file, upload and then use all small files for streaming MapReduce job?

Comment: Does it have to be XML? 4GB will take and cost a fair bit. It would be more efficient to convert it to a less verbose format like json to get it into S3 or at least compress it if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

You should either put this xml into a sequencefile and bzip2 it, or bzip2 it and decompress it in the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload one big file, S3 supports multi-part uploads. For more details start at the [documentation page](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html).

Comment: Thanks, multipart upload seems the right option. Would it be better for Hadoop to use, for example, 1gb files or smaller as an input, than 1 4gb file, or there is no difference?

Comment: @Ekaterina Prigara Sorry, that's a question I can't accurately answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to fit these data into EMR (Spark or Flink etc.), multiple compressed small files would be more desirable to leverage bit of the parallelism in loading, also e.g., EMR Spark can handle tar/zip compressed files from S3 by default.